# Search unique values between 2 txt files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have got 2 TXT files :

```
$file 1

water
bottle
train
car
bus

$file 2 

coffee
lamp
sport
train
book
```

I want to get the same value present in these 2 files, in that case the result expected is "train".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use Compare-Object with the -IncludeEqual and -ExcludeDifferent switches ala:

```
Compare-Object (GC file1.txt) -Diff (gc file2.txt) -includeequal -excludedifferent
```

Add -Passthrough to the end and the only output you get is the value(s) you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file1 = Get-Content file1

Get-Content file2 | where { $file1 -contains $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution :

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (gc .\file1.txt) -DifferenceObject (gc .\file2.txt) -IncludeEqual | Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}
```